# Are all these anti-wind questions coming from the same user?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Over the last few months I've noticed a number of questions from new users that seem to take an anti-wind power stance:

- [Does the cost of wind energy double when calculated correctly?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9574/3379)
- [Have wind installations peaked?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9544/3379)
- [Is wind power practically dead?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/8333/3379)
- [Are trees more productive than wind turbines?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/6566/3379)

The last one also has a [comment](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/are-trees-more-productive-than-wind-turbines#comment11142_6566) from another un-registered user, as well as two (since-deleted) answers from two more un-registered users ([one](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/5652/user5652) and [two](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/5667/user5667?tab=profile)). Since all of these are also anti-wind, I wouldn't be surprised if they're all the same person too.

All of them have a few things in common:

- The user is un-registered
- Images and data are not consistently sourced
- Low-quality -- questions are closed or downvoted

Is there a way to see if this is all coming from the same user?

*Should* anything be done about this? *Can* anything be done about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wondering the same, but found no hard evidence that confirms that all posts are from the same person with one exception; the user who asked the question [Are trees more productive than wind turbines?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/are-trees-more-productive-than-wind-turbines/6570#6570) also wrote an answer to that question using a different account, but action against this was already taken (the answer was deleted).

In any case we are monitoring this.
What the community can do is down-vote poor questions or flag them if they are really terrible. You can also vote to delete closed questions, but I'm not sure we have enough users who have voting rights for that.

Comment: SE Earth Science has a situation where rock identification questions are no longer acceptable, so all such questions have been closed & a process to delete them has started, but it's slow going. Users with a rep above 10k can vote to close 15 questions per day. I think users with a rep between 2k & 10k can only vote to close 5 questions per day.